# Why is my PathResource not readable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I try to write a Spring Batch application that reads a csv-file
and stores its contents in a database. I am not able to create
a `FlatFileItemReader` because I get an `IllegalStateException`
stating that the *Input resource must be readable
(reader is in 'strict' mode)*.

This is my configuration for the reader:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<CadSystem> cadSystemReader(final Path backupDirectory,
        final CadSystemFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper) {
    final FlatFileItemReader<CadSystem> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    final DefaultLineMapper<CadSystem> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    final PathResource resource = new PathResource(backupDirectory.resolve("cad_systems.csv"));

    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";"));
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    reader.setResource(resource);
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    return reader;
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:210)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must be readable (reader is in 'strict' mode): path [D:\backup\cad_systems.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:259)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

The file exists at `D:\backup\cad_systems.csv` and it is readable for all users/groups.

What causes this error?

**Update**

I tried to use a `FileSystemResource` like this

```
final FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(backupDirectory.resolve("cad_systems.csv").toFile());
```

and now it works. But what is wrong with the `PathResource`?

Comment: How do you specify `backupDirectory`? Does it have file: prefix, like file:D:\backup\?

Comment: I defined it in `application.properties` as `D:\backup`. The `Path` is obtained using `Paths::get()`.

Comment: Can you try to define it as file:D:\backup?

Comment: I don't think that it changes anything. The path is constructed using `Paths::get()` and this path is correct. The method would not understand the `file:` prefix. I updated the question with a workaround.

Comment: Which is the FQN of PathResource?

Comment: The difference is how the readable calculation is done, but this feels more like a java bug than one of Spring.  `PathResource` calculates if a file is readable using the java.nio.file.Files utility: `return (Files.isReadable(this.path) && !Files.isDirectory(this.path));`  Where as `FileSystemResource` just asks the file itself: `return (this.file.canRead() && !this.file.isDirectory());`

Comment: You are right. `Files::isReadable()` returns `false` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by a [bug in the JDK 7](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7168172). The issue does not occur when using Java 8.